# Size Classes with AutoLayout and ScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, scrollview

Ok. I'm new to size classes. I have a tabbed application, and the first tab "*Home*" has a series of 6 buttons with labels arranged circularly around a 7th.

I have the hierarchy:

```
MainView  
-ScrollView
    -*ContentView1
        -Buttons/Labels
    -*ContentView2
        -Buttons/Labels
```

Looks like this:

[image: a]
My `MainView` size is the `W-any`, `H-any` generic sized VC.
My `scrollView` is `451 pts` tall and `600 pts` wide.
My `contentViews` are `320 pts` tall and `453 pts` wide.

My problem is that the views aren't working on the 6+, 5 or 4S screens.
They only align properly on the 6 screen.

I'd like to be able to use size classes, but there is so much constraint activity going on, it's feeling a bit overwhelming.

I'm just looking for some advice/guidance on how to proceed. Perhaps even just some general principles to follow when using auto layout with size classes.

Answer (score 0):

I always find the most productive thing is to make it very simple and then get IBOutlets of some constraints and code it. I always get stuck in issues like this. Believe me, coding such scenario is more elegant than using interface builder, besides you will make a reusable component (or at least function) that you can use later in other projects.

You can even create views (Buttons/Labels) programtically